# How to mock user object to use get function of User class in drupal 8?

Tags: unit-testing, drupal, drupal-8, phpunit

I have written a custom service function which receive user id and get user details as an array. I have create one UserWrapper for User::load static function. But when i am running the test case I am getting error for $user->get() function.
Please guide me how to mock user object to use $user->get(). Please see the mock i have used bellow,

```
   $user_data = (object)[
  'first_name' => (object)[
    'value' => 'test'
  ],
  'field_middle_name' => (object)[
    'value' => 'test'
  ],
  'last_name' => (object)[
    'value' => 'test'
  ],
  'mail' => (object)[
    'value' => 'test@test.com'
  ],
  'field_telephone_number' => (object)[
    'value' => '9876543210'
  ],
  'field_mobile_number' => (object)[
    'value' => '9876543210'
  ],
];

$this->user
  ->method('load')
  ->willReturn($user_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$userDrupal = $this
  ->getMockBuilder(\Drupal\user\Entity\User::class)
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();

$entityStorageInterface = $this
  ->getMockBuilder(EntityStorageInterface::class)
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->setMethods(get_class_methods(EntityStorageInterface::class))
  ->getMock();
$entityStorageInterface
  ->expects($this->any())
  ->method('load')
  ->willReturn($userDrupal);


$entityTypeRepository = $this
  ->getMockBuilder(EntityTypeRepository::class)
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
$container->set('entity_type.repository', $entityTypeRepository);

$entityTypeManagerService = $this
  ->getMockBuilder(EntityTypeManagerInterface::class)
  ->getMock();
$entityTypeManagerService
  ->expects($this->any())
  ->method('getStorage')
  ->willReturn($entityStorageInterface);
$container->set('entity_type.manager', $entityTypeManagerService);
```